# add field text to the <p> after .change() with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to jquery. What I want to do is to change the "p" value everytime user changes the input field with syntax like "Input changed to: " and then the value from input field. My code doesn't work. Anyone could explain to me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myinput").change(function() {
    var str = $("#myinput").val();  
    $( "p" ).text(str);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



<input type="text" id="myinput">
<p> Text changed to: </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The onchange event is triggered by onblur event. So, if you don't switch the focus out of the input box, it does not work.

Comment: I know but even with clicking outside the box it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay the solution was simple. I should have used the .append() function instead of .text().

Answer (score 0):

The change event will run the function when the textbox changes focus (i.e mouse leaves the textbox). To run the function every time the user types a button, try the **keyup** event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myinput").keyup(function() {
    var str = $("#myinput").val();  
    $( "p" ).text(str);
  });
});
```

Heres a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8wra05sy/